# np.vstack() with datetime and float data types

Tags: arrays, numpy, dtype

I have a Pandas dataframe with datetime elements ('date') and floats ('cups) and am wondering if there's anyway to use `np.vstack()` to stack the two.

Previously, I had converted the datetime elements to floats and used `vstack()` without issue. However, I am using `xx` to update a scatterplot with a slider and, since I would like the plot to use dates, can no longer use this method.

```
xx = np.vstack((df['date'], df['cups']))
scat.set_offsets(xx.T)
```

I see that there's been a similar question, but I'm not sure how to adapt the answer given there to my situation: [Can ndarray store datetime and float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209612/can-ndarray-store-datetime-and-float).

Since the end-goal is to call `set_offsets` with the right kind of structure, the solution need not use vstack. I'm just not sure how to get the structure `set_offsets` needs without using `vstack`.

Comment: A numpy array can't store a mix of dtypes, unless you create a `structured` array.  Why don't you stick with a dataframe which can have different dtypes in its columns?  We don't what this offsets function is, or what it requires.

Comment: What does this offset function accept?

Comment: Sorry, assumed too much background knowledge. `set_offests` is a function of `ax.scatter`. The example linked [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/animation/rain.html) shows one use of it. I'm using it more along the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368990/scatter-plot-with-a-slider-in-python) example, which is why, @hpaulj, I'm not sure sticking with dataframes will work for my situation. Am I missing something?

Comment: What does `scat.get_offsets()` produce?  How does that compare with the arrays which you used to create the scatter in the first place?

Comment: When I experiment with a simple `scatter` with a `dates` axis, `get_offsets` gives a masked array with float values.  The dates have been converted to float values.  I believe your `set_offsets` values need to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Thanks to @hpaulj for the pointer. I was wrongly assuming that `scat.set_offsets()` needed datetime input for a plot with dates, so was resistant to passing floats. It turns out, however, that a date scatter plot can accept floats passed to `set_offsets` and still display the data correctly.

I've converted the column in question via the following:

`df.loc[:, 'date'] = df['date'].map(lambda x: matplotlib.dates.date2num(x))`.